# ¿Cómo se llama el juego infantil del proyectil?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, identificación-de-término, juegos

Por favor ayúdenme a traducir adecuadamente el nombre del juego infantil del proyectil, que en inglés se denomina [*catch*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch_(game)) (coger, atrapar, alcanzar, etc.) para todo tipo de proyectil. Después de buscar durante un rato, había visto algunas referencias a un *juego de atrape*, pero las alternativas también se demostraron. ¿Cómo se llama el juego generalmente?

[image: Niños al juego]

[image: Caso del futbol americano]

[image: Disco volante]

Comment: Quizá podría depender del objeto, porque en el último caso se podría decir "jugar al/con el "frisbi" (creo que nadie pronuncia como se escribe "frisbee"). Yo creo que en general es "jugar a lanzar", quizá a "pasar la pelota" para los más pequeños.

Comment: @Diego, vale. Cabe notar que el "frisbi" admite muchos otros juegos.

Comment: The problem is that in the US they play with their hands and in the Spanish-speaking world they play with their feet. I would go with jugar...

Comment: Para "play catch" I'd say "jugar a cachar [la pelota/la bola]" but when I looked for some documentation I found that that would *not* work in some countries!

Answer (score 2):

En España, el juego de *catch* es poco común. Probablemente, la razón es que los deportes populares en España (fútbol, baloncesto) no se basan tanto en esta acción. Por eso, no tenemos un nombre único para describir un juego en el que se lanza y atrapa un proyectil arbitrario.

Para referirnos a este juego, utilizamos el nombre del proyectil. Así, se dice "jugar al *frisbee*" o "jugar a la pelota". Si se quiere especificar más, se puede decir "jugar a pasarse la pelota".

Comment: +1, creo que esto lo contesta para muchos casos, pero decir "jugar al beisbol" sería muy confundido. Supongo que el juego necesita un corto nombre en los países beisboleros del Caribe.

Comment: No entiendo en qué sentido sería confundido.... // Creo que también se puede decir *jugar al beis*, por si eso te ayuda.  Pero el beisbol incluye much mas que solo lanzar y cachar la pelota.

Comment: @AaronBrick pasarse la pelota de béisbol es un juego que en España no se practica casi nunca, así que no tenemos un nombre mejor que "jugar a pasarse la pelota de béisbol". A diferencia de los ingleses, la palabra *béisbol* en España no se usa para referirse a la *pelota de béisbol*, sino solo al deporte.

Comment: Ya que en España no lo juega, quizás no es el lugar en que debemos buscar un nombre.

Comment: Esse juego tampoco es popular en Sudamérica. De hecho, creo que sólo lo he visto con los balones de béisbol y de fútbol americano en películas de EE. UU. Lo único que (raramente) se ve es el frisbee.

Answer (score 1):

Otra respuesta que de repente hallé: al recoger mi hija de la cancha del baloncesto del preescolar, ella estuvo jugando esto con su maestra. No sé de que país es esa mujer, pero al preguntarselo, me contestó que el juego se llama **"atrapar la pelota"** o **"cachar la pelota"**. Cuadra con la especificación del proyectil que mencionó wimi, si bien no con el verbo.

Comment: Esto es en Sudamérica? No he oído nunca "cachar" en España.

Comment: @wimi cachar parece ser un anglicismo popular en México. En Colombia nunca decimos eso. Además según RAE *cachar* es hacer algo pedazos. https://dle.rae.es/cachar

Comment: @wimi Estoy en California. Más allá del español mexicano que ostenta _cachar_, es muy común usado en sentido figurativo en Chile.

Comment: @Aaron Brick Sí. Por ejemplo, en Chile podrías escuchar: "Ese gallo es muy malaonda, _cachái_, no quiero tratar con él". Significa básicamente captar un concepto.

Answer (score 0):

Coincido acerca del probable componente cultural-deportivo (y la preeminencia del fútbol jugado con los pies) como explicación inicial para el hecho de que no parezca haber una expresión unívoca del juego del 'catch' (lanzar y atrapar a mano un objeto, como en el béisbol y el softbal).

Habría que preguntar, o esperar, la contestación proveniente de quienes viven en países hispano hablantes donde el juego de pasarse una bola, a la manera de práctica está extendido y es altamente popular (y desde donde surgen jugadores estrella, como ocurre en la República Dominicana, El Salvador, Cuba, Panamá, Puerto Rico y varios otros)

En Argentina, con los deportes de pelota (fútbol/basket/voley, etc) al acto de practicar arrojándonos alternadamente el balón, le llamamos

> [jugar a / practicar ] hacer **pases**

En el caso del freesbe (donde su juego de competencia —[Ultimate Freesbe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_(sport))— es escasamente conocido), normalmente decimos:

> ***tirar*** el freesbee 
> (*atraparlo esta tácitamente implicado*)